# Macbook Pro does not wake up from sleep, unless forced reset

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, touch-bar

My 15 inch Macbook Pro (TouchBar) 2017, will sleep after the correct time but will not wake. on touch of the trackpad or press of the keys, the keyboard will light up and sometimes the fans come on. but no matter how long you leave it (hours+) it will not wake to the login screen.

I have indeed reset the NVRAM and SMC and boot into safe mode following an older guide to a similar problem -> [Macbook does not wake up properly after several hours of sleep](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337635/macbook-does-not-wake-up-properly-after-several-hours-of-sleep) to no avail.

it is relly quite infuriating having to force shutdown my macbook and reboot it every time I take slightly longer to make a sandwich, especially when working on my university projects.

NB* not sure if this is relevant but I had to take it into genius repair for a damaged screen (£669) where they replaced the whole topcover in february.

I saw in the other post, a lot of people requested a `pmset -g assertions` so i've provided that below.

```
Assertion status system-wide:
   BackgroundTask                 0
   ApplePushServiceTask           0
   UserIsActive                   1
   PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    0
   PreventSystemSleep             0
   ExternalMedia                  0
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     1
   NetworkClientActive            0
Listed by owning process:
   pid 483(sharingd): [0x000003cd00018270] 00:00:57 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "Handoff"  
   pid 332(mds_stores): [0x000003f6000b82ae] 00:00:16 BackgroundTask named: "com.apple.metadata.mds_stores.power"  
   pid 181(hidd): [0x0000002c000980e6] 00:00:00 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle serviceID:10000039c name:AppleHIDKeyboardEve product:Apple Internal Keyb eventType:3"  
    Timeout will fire in 600 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
   pid 148(mds): [0x00000403000b82af] 00:00:03 BackgroundTask named: "com.apple.metadata.mds.power"  
Kernel Assertions: 0x100=MAGICWAKE
   id=504  level=255 0x100=MAGICWAKE mod=01/01/1970, 01:00 description=llw0 owner=IOSkywalkNetworkBSDClient
   id=505  level=255 0x100=MAGICWAKE mod=01/01/1970, 01:00 description=en0 owner=en0
Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler
```

Comment: I have the same problem with a 2020 MBA.

Comment: @carbocation did you ever discover a solution

Comment: I did not, @Xray25. I ended up factory resetting it, but don't know if that fixed the problem because I did so in the process of swapping it for an M1 (which doesn't have this problem).